# Is there a way to use for loops to display quotients and products of array numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, button

Need help with assignment. I need to create a button that uses a for loop to multiply each number in the array by the number after it into a second array and display the result. Lastly create another button that uses a while loop that divides each number in the array by the number after it into a third array and once more display the result. I have created a way to input numbers into an array "numbers" and display the array but do not know how to use for loops to display the quotient nor the product please help :(

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="SortFunction()">Sort it</button>
<button onclick="AddFunction()">Add it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myarray =[] ;
var text ;

function myFunction()
{
var fLen ;
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
var i ;
myarray.push(Number(x));
fLen = myarray.length ;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
  text += "<li>" + myarray[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function SortFunction()
{
myarray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;
}

function AddFunction()
 {
var sum = 0 ;
var fLen ;
var i ;
fLen = myarray.length ;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
 sum = sum + Number(myarray[i]);
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simply you could add these buttons and try to create some special logic for each button inside relevant function, for example `MultiplyNumbers()` and `DivideNumbers()`:

```
<button onclick="MultiplyNumbers()">Multiply pairs</button>
<button onclick="DivideNumbers()">Divide pairs</button>
```

In both functions firstly you should check if the main array has paired values via dividing length with 2 -> `length % 2 == 0`, then check if they're valid numbers with  [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function, if some value in pair is not valid you can define the result of this math equal `0` or what you want. Dividing function request also checking the second value in each pair with `0`, cause you can't divide a number with zero(or you can).

So, the first function works via `for` loop, the second one via `while` loop.

The snippet below shows you this two functions, they're work correctly with this simple rules. If I've missed something you can tell me.

```js
var myarray =[] ;
var text ;

function myFunction()
{
var fLen ;
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
var i ;
myarray.push(Number(x));
fLen = myarray.length ;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
  text += "<li>" + myarray[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function SortFunction()
{
myarray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;
}

function AddFunction()
 {
var sum = 0 ;
var fLen ;
var i ;
fLen = myarray.length ;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
 sum = sum + Number(myarray[i]);
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
 }
 
  function MultiplyNumbers() { 
        let multNumbers = [];
        
        if (myarray.length % 2 == 0){
        let actions = myarray.length / 2;
                    
           for(let i = 0; i < actions; i++){ 
               var tmult = (isNaN(myarray[i*2]) || isNaN(myarray[i*2+1])) ? 
               0 : 
               Number(myarray[i*2]) * Number(myarray[i*2+1]);
               multNumbers.push(tmult);
           }
        
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = multNumbers;
        } 
 }
 
  function DivideNumbers() { 
        let divNumbers = [];
        
        if (myarray.length % 2 == 0){
        let actions = myarray.length / 2;
            
           let i = 0;
           while(i<actions){
           
           var tdiv = (isNaN(myarray[i*2]) || isNaN(myarray[i*2+1]) || Number(myarray[i*2+1]) == 0) ? 
           0 : 
           Number(myarray[i*2]) / Number(myarray[i*2+1]);
           divNumbers.push(tdiv);
           
           i++;
           } 
        
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = divNumbers;
        } 
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="SortFunction()">Sort it</button>
<button onclick="AddFunction()">Add it</button>
<button onclick="MultiplyNumbers()">Multiply pairs</button>
<button onclick="DivideNumbers()">Divide pairs</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myarray =[] ;
var text ;

function myFunction()
{
var fLen ;
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
var i ;
myarray.push(Number(x));
fLen = myarray.length ;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
  text += "<li>" + myarray[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function SortFunction()
{
myarray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarray;
}

function AddFunction()
 {
var sum = 0 ;
var fLen ;
var i ;
fLen = myarray.length ;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++)
 {
 sum = sum + Number(myarray[i]);
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
 }
 
 
 // updated code
 var secondArray=[];
 function multiplyFunction(){
   var temp =  document.getElementById("num").value;
   for(i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
      secondArray.push(Number(temp) * myarray[i]);
   }
   // show new array ..
     text = "<ul>";
     for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
       text += "<li>" + secondArray[i] + "</li>";
     }
     text += "</ul>";
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
   //
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="num" min="0" max="100">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="SortFunction()">Sort it</button>
<button onclick="AddFunction()">Add it</button>
<button onclick="multiplyFunction()">Multiply</button>
<button onclick="divideFunction()">Divide</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your example shows? How OP should not to do?